# Emacs indent-line-function

Tags: emacs, elisp

i try to indent sql file lines in emacs, I think the c-indent-line is pretty good for me, so i write this code to my init file:

```
(defun my-sql-mode ()
    (setq indent-line-function 'c-indent-line)
    )

(add-hook 'sql-mode-hook 'my-sql-mode)
```

But when i use tab to indent the line, it always give me the tips of 'Wrong type argument: stringp, nil'.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation in Emacs is generally intelligent, but it's not magic.

`c-indent-line` is a function designed for use with C and C++ code. It shouldn't be greatly surprising that it might not work in other contexts, and I'm not sure what you were expecting it to do when faced with SQL code?

I'm afraid the answer is simply: Don't do that.

If you tell us what you wanted it to do, however, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I think he wants his SQL code to be indented like his C/C++ code and thinks that that's what the `indent-line-function` is supposed to do. What he fails to understand is that while it is indeed responsible for how a line looks after indentation it also has to parse and understand the buffer contents in order to determine how to indent a particular line. For you, @phils, it's obvious that `c-indent-line` cannot understand SQL code and hence the failure, for @Eorza it is not so clear.

Comment: True, there *are* other programming modes based on c-mode which can therefore use same indentation machinery with appropriate configuration. And while you could, as you say, add the necessary configuration to prevent errors in this case, it seems like a rather strange approach as SQL and C have virtually nothing in common.